# How do I get the submit button to display properly with correct color instead of half being black?

Tags: adobe, submit-button, business-catalyst

The page with the problem is located at http://blue123a.businesscatalyst.com/select. The theme is called Forceful.

I made a new site and created a new form. When I added the form into the page, there was a problem with the submit button. One of the only things I found that may be relevant is to move the button up on the z-axis (I believe), but I don't know how to do that either.

The button works properly, but it is not displaying correctly.

Thanks.

Update 10/23/2014 Steve88 partially answered my initial question. The css change did make one color show left to right, shows white instead of aqua, on the submit button; it also got rid of the black half of the button. It gave me a transparent gray box on part of the button and made the button square though.

I did more digging and found answers at www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3891201 and www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp that helped me get back the rounded corners.

Adding CSS code for border-radius gave me the corners I wanted. Included -moz-border-radius and -webkit-border-radius for additional crossbrowser compatability.

I also got the button hover to work correctly.

...Original CSS...

FOR BUTTON (There is more code, but this is the essential part.)

```
.webform .cat_button {
background: url("../images/buttons/submit_button.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 0 rgba
(0, 0, 0, 0);
border: 0 none;
```

FOR BUTTON HOVER

```
.webform .cat_button:hover {
background: url(../images/buttons/submit_button.png) no-repeat 100% -39px; }
```

....CSS With Adjustments...

FOR BUTTON

```
.webform .cat_button {
background: url("../images/buttons/submit_button.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0     
transparent;
border: 0 none;
border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
```

FOR BUTTON HOVER

```
.webform .cat_button:hover {
background: url(../images/buttons/submit_button.png) 0 -39px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your background style to this:

background: url("../images/buttons/submit_button.png") repeat 50% 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

its on line 1614 in style.css

Comment: Thanks. I tested your suggestion "background: url("../images/buttons/submit_button.png") repeat 50% 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);". Makes the button square and white. Now there is a transparent gray box going from the top of the button almost to the bottom.

Comment: Im not sure I know exactly what your trying to achieve?